# insert child mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, parent-child, foreign-key-relationship, insert-into

I've got a newbie question...

I've got two tables:

```
parentTable
-----------
id_user int(11) not null auto increment primary key,
email varchar(64),
pass varchar(64)

childTable
----------
id_user int(11) not null, 
name varchar(64), 
address varchar(512), 
foreign key (id_user) references parentTable(id_user) 
on update cascade 
on delete restrict
```

Now can I insert:

```
insert into childTable (id_user) select id_user from parentTable where id_user = '1'
```

But I just want to insert also name and address values.

Sorry for the newbie question, but I lurked for a day and found nothing.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: sorry, changed a few minutes ago, italian word for "user"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting part about your query is that you *know* the `id_user` you're trying to select to insert - it's in your `WHERE` clause.

If you will always know the `id_user`, you can skip the extra `SELECT` portion of the query and directly do:

```
INSERT INTO childTable (id_user, name, address) VALUES (1, 'some name', '123 test street');
```

If you, for some other reason, need the additional `SELECT`, you can append the `name`/`address` values directly into the field-list, like this:

```
INSERT INTO childTable (id_user, name, address)
    SELECT id_user, 'some name', '123 test street' FROM parentTable WHERE id_user = '1';
```

Comment: You are my hero, lol :D

Thank you: i was searching for this answer for an entire day.